# How to send an email with status of Application installation using Powershell

Tags: email, powershell

I am trying to install an .msi remotely in multiple servers using powershell script. I was able to install the msi successfully with below script. 
I want to add email functionality to this script which can give Application installation status (success or failure) and server name details.

I have tried couple of ways but not working, Can you please help me to include this email functionality (Need Status of Application installation and server name details in Email after script execution). Please let me know if you need any other details from me

```
#Variables
$computername = Get-Content 'D:\server.txt'
$sourcefile = "D:\test.msi"    
#This section will install the software 
foreach ($computer in $computername) 
{
    $destinationFolder = "\\$computer\C$\download\"
    #This section will copy the $sourcefile to the $destinationfolder. If the Folder does not exist it will create it.
    if (!(Test-Path -path $destinationFolder))
    {
        New-Item $destinationFolder -Type Directory
    }
    Copy-Item -Path $sourcefile -Destination $destinationFolder
    Invoke-Command -ComputerName $computer -ScriptBlock { & cmd /c "msiexec.exe /log C:\download\Installation.log /i c:\download\test.msi" /qn ADVANCED_OPTIONS=1 CHANNEL=100}
```

Comment: Try adding a try,catch,finally block and look at the Send-MailMessage cmdlet.

Comment: @ stephen: Can you please edit the script with your suggestion ? I will give a try. I am not sure how to put that try & catch.

Comment: Please take a look at get-help about_Try_Catch_Finally  it explains the fundamentals. I would recommend using the ISE as well to develop your script as it contains syntax higlighting and code snippets. Try to modify your code and if it fails post what you tried and what errors you get.